# using a local C# DataTable with SqlBulkCopy

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, datatable, sqlbulkcopy

as there is so many of them, examples.. i was researching online, though they do not show use of `SqlBulkCopy`, in the folowing scenario :

i have used a query in order to fetch existing Data from SqlServer(2008), into a `DataTable`, 
so i could sort the data locally, and avoid hitting database while processing.

so now, at that stage, i already have the option to clone the source dataTable Schema 
using `localDataTable = DataTableFromOnlineSqlServer.Clone();`

by doing that `Clone()`,  i now have all the columns, and each of the column-dataType.

then in next stage of the program, i am filling the Cloned-From-Db,  - that Local (yet Empty) new `DataTable` with some new data .

so by now i have a populated `DataTable`, and it's ready to be stored in sql server .

using this code below yeld no results

```
    public string UpdateDBWithNewDtUsingSQLBulkCopy(DataTable TheLocalDtToPush, string TheOnlineSQLTableName)
    {

        // Open a connection to the AdventureWorks database. 
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(RCLDBCONString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            // Perform an initial count on the destination table.
            SqlCommand commandRowCount = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+TheOnlineSQLTableName +";", connection);
            long countStart = System.Convert.ToInt32(commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());

            var nl = "\r\n";
            string retStrReport = "";
            retStrReport = string.Concat(string.Format("Starting row count = {0}", countStart), nl);
            retStrReport += string.Concat("==================================================", nl);
            // Create a table with some rows. 
            DataTable newCustomers = TheLocalDtToPush;

            // Create the SqlBulkCopy object.  
            // Note that the column positions in the source DataTable  
            // match the column positions in the destination table so  
            // there is no need to map columns.  
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
            {
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = TheOnlineSQLTableName;

                try
                {
                    // Write from the source to the destination.
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(newCustomers);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
            }

            // Perform a final count on the destination  
            // table to see how many rows were added. 
            long countEnd = System.Convert.ToInt32(
                commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());

            retStrReport += string.Concat(string.Format("Ending row count = {0}", countEnd), nl);
            retStrReport += string.Concat("==================================================", nl);
            retStrReport += string.Concat(string.Format("{0} rows were added.", countEnd - countStart),nl);
            retStrReport += string.Concat("New Customers Was updated successfully", nl, "END OF PROCESS !");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return retStrReport;
        }
}
```

now The problem is, that  No data was inserted at all.

i have made some resarch and there is no solution for me 
i also checked to make sure that :

1. all the columns of source and destination are aligned (although
   it is a clone so no wories)
2. that there is a `PK` set as `IDENTITY`
   column on the Sql server table

what am i missing here ?

...the "report" i have made, in order to calculate inserted rows tells

*" 0 rows were added "*

and thats it no Errors or exeptions reported /thrown .

Comment: Did you check SQL error log, I suspect that your localDT has same primary key as online one. I suggest not to put any value in primary field if you do not have Enable Identity Insert for auto increment column. Also if you are putting lot of fields, try with small set of data first.

Comment: please let me know how do i check on that issue of the error log & if i made a clone , but i did not fill the custId(pk) - it is identity auto incremented, does the bulkCopy takes care of the issue of - source online has a record custId =1 , does it sinc' the process of insertation ?

Comment: @SumitGupta what i think is this is simple and i lack the experience with SqlBulkCopy. BTW i Did Use around 230 records . is it too\ much (:

Comment: @LoneXcoder Could you check your `TheOnlineSQLTableName` again? Your code seems to look OK to me.

Comment: @KingKing i am checking again although i copy paseted `[dbo].[tblCustomers]` as a string

Comment: @LoneXcoder are you sure `TheLocalDtToPush` has any row? I'm not sure about the default DataRowState which affects how `SqlBulkCopy` works, so for sure you can try passing a specified `DataRowState` (such as DataRowState.Added) as the second param into `SqlBulkCopy()` and see if it makes any shake.

Comment: @KingKing
i am viewing in the breakpoints it has around 200 records(no custId !!) , now for the row state, pleas post some code for that perticular stage in the scope of using...PLS

Comment: @LoneXcoder `bulkCopy.WriteToServer(newCustomers, DataRowState.Added);` I'm not sure, you can try with `DataRowState.Unchanged`, ...

Comment: @KingKing i am trying them both now ..., i am putting us into a chat/discussion "room"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31525/discussion-between-lonexcoder-and-king-king)

Comment: hope you find the solution by now, I use bulkcopy couple of time and I check those code and what I did is I use DataTable with 1 record from table and then add more rows to it, and then give to bulkcopy. 230 rows are low :p.

Comment: @SumitGupta you were right the limit is around 50 in 50 still dead 40 - 30 is max ! where do i find out why , is it the size of bandwith ? is it computers mem ? what the heck and why don't i get an error of any kind ? to mamy rows was loaded ither from sql ssms or vs 2010

Comment: @SumitGupta my mistake . i was not sorting the data properly , that lead me to try insert a biger size string than i allowed in the sql server (nvrachar[50] for email )... this was after i was searching information on bulkcopy limitaions in google, that gave me the idea to look in to the particiular row's data and see that in the specific row the data in specified column(size 50 chars) was out of limit .why didn't sql return to visual studio the message ?

Comment: as I said I never research on it, but Bulk copy simply ignore error or probably truncate the data, this is mandatory to allow copy of still validate data, or maybe there is some flag to switch it on/off on error reporting.